# Dynamis SQL joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement where I will need to build dynamic sql relating to joins.

All the information (the table names and the joining column) for the join statement will be contained in a table.

While I can easily get the table names, I cannot figure out how to construct the "source tables" dynamic join...

1. The first table should be the 'FROM', but how do I determine the first table (there may be up to 5 tables)
2. The following tables should be the 'LEFT JOIN ON', but how do I dynamically build the THIS = THAT and THIS = THAT parts?

Using STUFF, this is as close I I have gotten to solving solution, which is not much.

OHS_MRI_Encounter_RUSH ACT ON ACT, OHS_MRI_Insurance_RUSH INS ON INS, OHS_MRI_Patient_Account_RUSH R02 ON R02

I can replace the comma's with 'LEFT JOIN' and CONCAT the 'ON', but how would I make the dynamic INS.COLUMN1 = ACT.COLUMN1?  The ending result would be:

```
FROM OHS_MRI_Encounter_RUSH ACT ON ACT
LEFT JOIN OHS_MRI_Insurance_RUSH INS ON INS.COLUMN1 = ACT.COLUMN1 AND INS.COLUMN1 = 
R02.COLUMN1 
LEFT JOIN OHS_MRI_Patient_Account_RUSH R02 ON R02.COLUMN1 = ACT.COLUMN1 AND R02.COLUMN1 
= INS.COLUMN1
```

I tried implicit joins but this only works if all tables have relating rows, which, in my case, will not always be the case.

I must use dynamic SQL as the tables and columns will change.

Comment: Any Dynamic SQL solution can assemble queries on the fly, and can take care of the `FROM`/`JOIN` clauses. For example, in Java you can use MyBatis Dynamic SQL, but there are plenty of solutions out there for your specific language.

Comment: You have given such little information that we can use to actually understand your need. To help us help you... Write a query that returns all the table names and all the column names to be used. Show us the query and the results. Then write a query using static table names and column names as you need. Again, show the query and the results. Preferably, you would also include a small sampling of source data as well. After showing us all of that data, we might be able to help you along with the dynamic part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a solution, but imagining a detail that was not included in the question: where should the comparisons on the join criteria come from? For my answer, those comparisons must be on the commas' right.

```
DECLARE @source TABLE (dynamic_sql_info VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @source
VALUES ('
OHS_MRI_Encounter_RUSH ACT ON ACT, 
OHS_MRI_Insurance_RUSH INS ON INS.this=ACT.that and INS.other > ACT.another, 
OHS_MRI_Patient_Account_RUSH R02 ON R02.this=INS.that')

;WITH split_data AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ranking
        ,ss.table_name
        ,ss.condition
    FROM @source s
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT
        left(trimed.value, charindex(' ON ', trimed.value)) AS table_name
        ,right(trimed.value, len(trimed.value) - charindex(' ON ', trimed.value) - 3) AS condition
        FROM
        STRING_SPLIT(s.dynamic_sql_info, ',') split --Breaks it by commas
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT trim(split.value) value
        ) AS trimed
    ) AS ss
)
SELECT CASE sd.ranking
WHEN 1 THEN 'FROM '+sd.table_name
ELSE 'LEFT JOIN '+sd.table_name+' ON '+sd.condition
END AS table_instructions
FROM split_data sd
```

| table_instructions |
| --- |
| FROM OHS_MRI_Encounter_RUSH ACT |
| LEFT JOIN OHS_MRI_Insurance_RUSH INS ON INS.this=ACT.that and INS.other > ACT.another |
| LEFT JOIN OHS_MRI_Patient_Account_RUSH R02 ON R02.this=INS.that |

If this doesn't work for your data, please let me know, and provide more details.

You can see this running on [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9ZVJx7Oq).

Code for SQL Server older than 2016: [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r4agBxp_)

Comment: Thank you for your effort on this.   I get a message Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'

Comment: Oh, then it's the SQL Server version you are using. Those functions are SQL Server 2016+.
I have done another DB Fiddle with the same code, but using functions that work on older versions of SQL Server, you can see it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/r4agBxp_)